# What % of potassium sorbate, and or potassium benzoate do you need to add to a liquid solution, mixed with powders to keep yeast/mold from growing?

Tags: yeast, problems

What % of potassium sorbate, and or potassium benzoate do you need to add to a liquid solution, mixing water with fruit powders to keep yeast/mold from growing?

Answer (score 2):

- 0.5 tsp (1.7 g) Potassium Sorbate - treats 1 gallon mead, wine or fruit wine.
- 2.5 tsp (9.1 g) Potassium Sorbate  - treats 5 gallons

I wouldn't use benzoate stabilising as tablets were withdrawn (e.g. UK) due to concerns about the carcinogens.